# looking for an external graphics adapter that works for ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, video-adapters, ubuntu

I recently discovered that my laptop's USB Type C port doesn't support display so I'm looking to get an external graphics adapter that will add a 3rd monitor for me (I have an HDMI port but nothing else for video).

I saw some on Amazon, but don't know if they support Ubuntu. My laptop has USB 3 so I'm looking for an adapter that uses that as it has more speed to it.

in case you're curious about the laptop in question its a ASUS VivoBook Pro 17 N705UQ

Comment: What laptop do you have? How does the USB-C port not work?

Comment: Also, do you have a docking station?

Comment: I don't have a docking station, don't want one, I just want the hdmi connection. The USB Type C apparently doesn't take in video on my model (ASUS Tech Support told me that this morning) so I'm going with the next best item

Comment: updated question with my laptop model

Comment: Asus support is correct in that your USB-C port can't use an eGPU (only Thunderbolt 3 ports can do that), but mislead you in that it can *output* a video signal just fine. [Here's one such cable.](https://www.amazon.com/uni-Thunderbolt-Compatible-Pixelbook-More-Space/dp/B075V5JK36/ref=sr_1_5?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1515882286&sr=1-5&keywords=usb+c+to+hdmi)

Comment: Thanks for informing me that @JMY1000 I'll give that cable a try and see if it works.

Comment: I bought that one and it didn't work, I still get a black screen when connected, thinking an external adapter will be my only hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying [this Multi Monitor Video Graphics Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O6G5ZGI)* which wasn't working either until I disabled secure boot, curious to know if that prevented the other items I tried but I have what I wanted finally.

<sub><sup>* StarTech.com HD 1080p USB 3.0 to HDMI External Multi Monitor Video Graphics Adapter for Mac and PC</sup></sub>